# what location on an android device does the xamarin contact picker retrieve contacts from?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-contacts

It seems that android has different locations where it stores contacts (i.e. phone, SIM, google account).  I need to know the exact "path" that it uses to determine where to pull the contacts as I am having trouble with pulling contacts from a user device that isnt using the default path.  I believe I have already went through all previous posts for this topic without any luck and the Xamarin forums do not seem to have any answers either.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses the `ContactsContract.Data.ContentUri` to make a cursor to look up contacts.

This can be seen in the Xamarin.Mobile repository here: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Mobile/blob/master/MonoDroid/Xamarin.Mobile/Contacts/AddressBook.cs#L109

Comment: Thank you for the very quick response.  I appreciate that.  So, does the contactscontract.data.contenturi point to something like ..."/data/data/android.contacts.database/contacts.db" on the actual device?  (forget the exact path)  I ask because it seems that android has made that path different between different OS versions.  Is the Xamarin URI smart enough to pick up the right path for the right OS version?

Comment: The URI tells the Android ContentProvider what it wants. The provider itself knows where to look for the contacts. This source is not known from your app, since it uses the ContentProvider as a middle man. This ContentProvider can differ from Android version to Android version and in turn the source can be different.

Comment: Ok, that helps.  Also, one more question before this is solves my issue.  So, what you're saying then is that the provider will know where to look depending on the OS version.  If that's the case, then as long as a user has a "default" location setup for their contacts, this URI should pull from that source?  (as long as the app has READ_CONTACTS permission of course)

Comment: What do you mean with "as long as a user has a "default" location setup for their contacts"?

Comment: It would seem that in Android, a user can set their default contact location to be "SIM, Phone or Google account".  So, if a user has set their default location to "SIM", then the URI should try and pull contacts just from the SIM correct?

Comment: If there are no other accounts on the device with contacts, then as far as I know, yes. Given the permission in the manifest and at runtime.

Comment: Thanks Cheesebaron for your help.  This was helpful.